# Selecionando um Valor específico em Array Jquery

Tags: jquery, post

Olá, bom dia!
Sou iniciante na área e gostaria de (se possível) ajuda para resolver uma questão.

O usuário possuirá um campo para selecionar as cidades, ao selecionar, o sistema irá capturar a cidade escolhida e irá fazer uma consulta a uma base de dados para associar a um determinado ID.

Acontece que quando ele seleciona uma das opções de cidade hoje, o sistema lista todas as possíveis cidades e todos os outros estados.

Gostaria que ele entrasse no array, fizesse uma validação de UF == es e depois apresentasse somente a cidade escolhida com o o UF validado (refinar as opções).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edite seu posto inclua código em forma de texto.

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que o teste de existência é baseado no id pode utilizar map para o apanhar só os id e indexOf. Este dá -1 se não existe ou um índice positivo quando existe.

```js
//Essa é a lista

var arrayList = JSON.parse('[{"id":"1","name":"Fortaleza","uf":"CE"}]'); 

//funcao para gerar o objeto
function Employee(id, name, uf) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.uf = uf;
}

//detectando click no botao
// e obtendo os dados
$( ".btn" ).click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data("id").toString();
  var name = $(this).data("name");
  var uf = $(this).data("uf");
  
  //criando objeto
  var employeeObject1 = new Employee(id,name, uf);
  
  
  let index = arrayList.map(x=>x.id).indexOf(id); //apanhar o indice com map e indexOf
  if (index === -1){ 
    document.getElementById("cidades").innerHTML = "Não existe na lista";
  }
  else { 
    document.getElementById("cidades").innerHTML = "Existe na lista";
  }

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" data-id="1" data-name="fortaleza" data-uf="/CE">Selecionar cidade 1</button>

<button class="btn" data-id="2" data-name="São Paulo" data-uf="SP">Selecionar cidade 2</button>

<button class="btn" data-id="3" data-name="Rio de janeiro" data-uf="RJ">Selecionar cidade 3</button>



<div id="cidades"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia,

Um solução simples seria iterar neste array de cidades e criar um novo, somente com as cidades filtradas do ES.

```
var cidadesES = new Array();
cidade.forEach(function(obj) {
    if (obj.uf === "ES") {
        cidadesES.push(obj);
    }
});
```

O resultado seria um novo array, o qual você pode usar no campo de seleção.
Espero que tenha ajudado.